# Angular string returns, data doesnt

Tags: angular

Hello i have never face this before. On first console check the video returns ok but on data it doesn't return the video just signature and id? Any idea why? i have other functions and they work fine

page.ts

```
uploadTextSet() {
    let loader = this.loadingCtrl.create({
        spinner: 'crescent',
        dismissOnPageChange: true
    });
    loader.present();
    console.log(this.text);
    this.userData.upload(this.text,this.flowDetails.id)
    .map(res => res.json())
    .subscribe(data => {
        loader.dismiss(); 
        if (data.success) {
            swal({
                icon: "success",
                text: data.message,
                buttons: {
                    visible: false
                }
            });
        }
        else {
            swal({
                icon: "error",
                text: data.error,
                buttons: {
                    visible: false
                }
            });
        }
    },
    err => {
        loader.dismiss();
        alert('An error occurred, please check your internet connection');
    });
}//console.log(this.text) returns ok
```

user_data.ts

```
 upload(text: any,id:number) {
    let url = this.appData.getApiUrl() + 'upload';
    console.log(text);
    let data = this.jsonToURLEncoded({
        signature: this.signature,
        text: text,
        id: id
    });
    console.log(data);
    return this.http.post(url, data, this.options);
};
```

Comment: Could you please show the `jsonToURLEncoded()` function implementation? Also the argument is called `group_id` but I see you're assigning a variable called `id` to the property `id`? I don't see it defined in the function.

Comment: how the first console.log(data) print, you may need to index the object or the array

Comment: id is not getting passed in. also any reason you using global this.signature & this.options rather than passing them in? it's not a very encapsulated method.

Answer (score 0):

the problem was that i was passing the text as an array not a object

wrong 
     text:any=[];
right
    text:any={};